# Change coordinate system of a WMS service

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wms

I have a WMS service that is projected to UTM/SAD-69.

My workspace is in WGS-84 with no projection.

I want to change the coordinate system of my WMS service.

Is it possible in ArcMap 10.0?

The wms coordinate system is:

[image: Layer Properties in ArcMap]

More information from the Layer Properties (using ArcGIS 10.2) that show it to have a **Map Service Type** of **Cached**.

[image]

Comment: The WMS will advertise the CRS that it supports in its GetCapabilities response, you will only be able to use the CRS supported by the WMS in your desktop client (ArcMap).  What CRS are reported in the WMS?

Answer (score 1):

There's a topic on this in the help: [Setting the Coordinate System of a WMS service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/#/Setting_the_coordinate_system_of_a_WMS_service/00sp00000009000000/). You should see a list of available coordinate reference systems on the source tab of the layer's property page. If you set the data frame's coordinate reference system to one that is supported by the service, ArcMap will request the appropriate version of the service. If the data frame is using an unsupported coordinate reference system, ArcMap will request a supported version of the service and then project it on-the-fly (client-side) to the data frame's coordinate system.

Comment: Hi @mkennedy, actually I can't find that dialog box (Change coordinate system) in properties from my WMS. All the information of coordinate system that I have from my WMS is on the picture above... I can't find other avaiable coordinate system for this WMS. But thx in advance.

Comment: Is this a publicly accessible WMS that you can provide a service URL to so that we can test?

Comment: Yes @PolyGeo, it is public. If you click on "Add data from ArcGIS online..." and do a search for "Mosaico_2011_UTM", you will be able to see the WMS that I'm using.

Comment: @Ycavazin, I'm seeing the same thing. Maybe it's because it's a cached service on ArcGIS Online?? Setting the DF to 4326 (wgs84) with a transformation does work though.

Comment: Hi @mkennedy, I opened a blank map, with EPSG - 4326 system coordinates and then I've added the WMS, that seems to be still displaced. If I add Bing imagery layers, my shape-files has good alignment. Dunno what to do...

Comment: Mosaico_2011_UTM in ArcGIS Online doesn't appear to be a WMS