# Changing coordinate system in which WMS is served using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, wms, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to change the coordinate system of a WMS.
what i have tried is:

```
prjFile = lokaal + "opmeting_straatkolk.prj"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(prjFile)
mxd2 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for DF in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd2):
    DF.spatialReference = sr
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Have you seen http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103516/using-spatial-references-with-arcpy-after-prj-files-no-longer-installed-by-arc What do you mean by "no success"?  I am assuming that you are trying to change the coordinate system of a data frame into which you are projecting a WMS on-the-fly rather than trying to change the coordinate system in which the WMS is served.

Comment: I am using arcpy 10.3, and i want to change the coordinate system in which the WMS is served.

Comment: What GIS software is serving the WMS?  In any event this answer looks like it may be useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76530/115

Comment: no idea what GIS software is serving the WMS, but its located here: [link](http://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/omwrgbmrvl/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0)

Comment: And i need to do it in python...

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it!

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lokaal = r"D:\\Drive\\verwerk_straatkolken_uit_as-built_plannen\\"
prjFile = lokaal + "opmeting_straatkolk.prj"
prj = arcpy.SpatialReference(prjFile)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
df.spatialReference = prj
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```